# SQL UPDATE statment does nothing, but returns no error.

Tags: php, html, sql

```
<?php
require ("db/db.php"); 
$c_id = ($_POST['c_id']);
$c_title = ($_POST['c_title']);
$c_content = ($_POST['c_content']);

// echo place

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE content 
SET c_id = $c_id, c_title = $c_title, c_content = $c_content 
WHERE c_id = $c_id");

header("location: index.php");
?>
```

This is my code. 
when the header goes to the index, nothig has changed in the fields that are presented here.
i tried to echo the variables at the "echo place" and they all returned correct,
so i know that they are POSTed to the page.
i guess the error are in the SQL UPDATE statement, but PHP does not return any error to me,
it just goes directly to the index.php. 
when i try to run the SQL in phpmyadmin, whith value 1 instead of the variable, it changes all the fields to 1, so there it works.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Let me take a wild guess: ...quotes

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and are **BLINDLY** assuming your query can never ever possibly be wrong or fail.

Comment: It won't return an error because you aren't checking for one. `$sql` will be FALSE, because your query is failing, see @AwladLiton's answer for why it's failing.

Comment: Those are string values, wrap them in quotes

Comment: *"but PHP does not return any error to me"* --- Because you're not asking it to `?`, and/or let me take another even "wilder" guess: You're connecting with `mysqli_*` but querying using `mysql_*`? I stand at being 50% right and 50% wrong on this one; the *connection part* that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)
2. why your are updating the id of a table? you also need to change your query
3. use quotes in your php variable

Try like this:

```
require ("db/db.php"); 
$c_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['c_id']);
$c_title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['c_title']);
$c_content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['c_content']);

// echo place

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE content 
SET  c_title = '$c_title', c_content = '$c_content' 
WHERE c_id = $c_id limit 1") or die(mysql_error());

header("location: index.php");
```

You should switch to `mysqli` or `PDO` since `mysql_*` are outdated  and will be removed.

Comment: Upvoted, even though you were later you at least added in the `real_escape_string`.

Comment: why you guys misuses  the downvote button? give one valid reason for this and i can learn from this

Comment: @John Bertelsen : did you try this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, try this code (As I don't know the variables content, I put all of those with "'"

```
$sql = <<<SQL
   UPDATE content 
       SET c_id='{$c_id}', c_title='{$c_title'}, c_content='{$c_content}' 
       WHERE c_id='{$c_id}'
SQL;

$query = mysql_query($sql);
var_dump($query);
```

And if the `$query` returns true, put the `header('Location: index.php");` again